# How to get URL of Smart Poster in app launched by AAR

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

I have an NFC card with Smart Poster and AAR writen on it

```
NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(smartPosterRecord, aarRecord);
```

When I attach this card to the device my demo application defined in AAR starts, but `intent.getAction()` returns `android.intent.action.MAIN` instead of `NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED` or `NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED` so I can't get Tag from it.

How should it be done so that I can read URL from the smart poster?

Ndef:

```
NdefRecord uriRecord = NdefRecord.createUri(uri);
NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(uriRecord);

NdefRecord smartPosterRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_SMART_POSTER, new byte[0], message.toByteArray());
NdefRecord aarRecord = NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord(aar);

message = new NdefMessage(smartPosterRecord, aarRecord);

// Get instance of Ndef for the given tag
Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
// Enable I/O
ndef.connect();

// Write the message
ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);

// Close the connection
ndef.close();
```

Handling of intent:

```
public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (((NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()))) || (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()))) {
        // do something
    }
```

Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.demo.app.DemoActivity"
        android:label="GeneralDemo"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfcfilter" />

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this into manifest did the trick:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
             <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="demo.com" /> 
        </intent-filter>
```

The app is not starting because of the AAR however but as a result of "catching" the url of smart poster...

EDIT:
In the end we decided to use custom MimeType that we are catching in our app (via intent-filter)